# Javascript - how to synchronously preload images and then callback once they are all loaded

Tags: javascript, image, callback, synchronous, preloading

I'm trying to preload images from an array synchronously with a callback when all are done. I can find lots of solutions on here which get me near to where I want to be but none of them work synchronously and allow the usage I require.

The code I have below works great but all are loaded async. I have another script which does the job sequentially but I can't seem to fire a callback once all the items in the array are done. This code below allows for user defined callback outside of the function which is what I need as I'd be calling this function on different arrays.

What I'm attempting to do is preload one array of images, check a timestamp comparison previously stored in a variable to see whether the network is slow or not, then (if the network is slow) preload a second array of images using the same preload function when the first array is done, then fire my image slideshow function once the second array is done. This is to avoid starting my image slideshow before enough images are initially loaded - to avoid blank slides, if that makes sense.

Code which works but only asynchronously:

```
function preload(arr){
var newimages=[], loadedImages = 0;
var postaction=function(){}
var arr=(typeof arr!="object")? [arr] : arr;
function imageloadpost(){
    loadedImages++;
    if (loadedImages==arr.length){
        postaction(newimages); //call postaction and pass in newimages array as parameter
    }
}
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    newimages[i]=new Image();
    newimages[i].src=arr[i];
    newimages[i].onload=function(){
        imageloadpost();
    }
    newimages[i].onerror=function(){
        imageloadpost();
    }
}
return { //return blank object with done() method
    done:function(f){
        postaction=f || postaction; //remember user defined callback functions to be called when images load
    }
}
```

}

Sample result I want would be:

Image 1...Loaded, then...
Image 2...Loaded, then...
Image 3...Loaded, then...
Callback: all are loaded - do something else

**UPDATE**:

This is the synchronous code that waits for the first image to load before firing the function again for the second and third etc etc. This is the behaviour I want but can't seem to get a callback to work when all items in the array are loaded.

```
function preload(arrayOfImages, index) {
index = index || 0;
if (arrayOfImages && arrayOfImages.length && arrayOfImages.length > index) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        preload(arrayOfImages, index + 1);
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
        preload(arrayOfImages, index + 1);
    };
    img.src = arrayOfImages[index];
}
$j('#slide-' + index + '').addClass('loaded');
}
```

Comment: [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Image loading is always asynchronous because your callback code has to wait until the loading is finished.